# Seeking feedback on Machine Learning approach

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, methodology

Inspired by the [Harry Potter: Written by Artificial Intelligence](https://medium.com/deep-writing/harry-potter-written-by-artificial-intelligence-8a9431803da6) article that was going around a few days ago, I wanted to try my hand at creating a similar system.

I've taken the [Coursera Machine Learning course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome), so I have a (very!) basic understanding of the concepts involved in Neural Networks, but haven't implemented anything beyond the examples in that course.

My planned approach was to first train a Neural Network to recognize samples of my own writing (with the features/inputs being the presence of trigrams of words, and the ouput being a 0-1 value encoding the network's confidence that the example is a sample of my writing), then to use a genetic approach to generate more and more feasible sentences: generate a random string of words, generate multiple "children" by randomly mutating a word or two at a time, select those that the NN scores highest, and repeat.

However, this approach seems flawed due to the huge number of features involved. `nltk.corpus.words.words` has size 236736, so the set of all trigrams of words is of size `236736**3~=10**16` - which I imagine will render my operations time-consuming, to say the least (I recall from the ML course that it's a design smell for models to have more than 100,000 features). I could try to limit the trigrams to only those constructed from words that I've previously used - but, even with a severely-restricted vocabulary of 1000 words, I would have a billion features.

I was trying to write this while on a plane (and without internet), but I see now that there's a linked [guide](https://medium.com/deep-writing/how-to-write-with-artificial-intelligence-45747ed073c). Still, I'd like some feedback on my original approach.

Is my general approach (train NN to recognize my writing, use NN as fitness measure for a genetic algorithm) sound, and I just need to select features differently? Or does is this entire strategy infeasible and I should approach this problem a different way?

Comment: Thanks for the suggested tag! This is my first post on this site (recommended from https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms)